# Why Unsafe query: Delete statement without where clears all data in the table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, sql-delete

I have the following query in Redshift:

```
delete * from a
left join s on a.order_id = s.id
where s.order_id is not null
```

When I try to execute it, it gives me back the warning of the title. However, it does have a where clause, so I am wondering why this appear.

Maybe it is because the where clause makes reference to the query of the join and not the other? If so, how could avoid this warning?

Comment: I removed the `postgresql` because no such warning exists there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution (for maintaining the join) was to delete the `*`.

```sql
delete from a
left join s on a.order_id = s.id
where s.order_id is not null
```

Comment: I'm trying to compose a similar delete statement in Redshift, except looking for rows that do not exist in `s` by using `WHERE s.order_id IS NULL` but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You could attempt to rewrite it, something like:

```sql
DELETE FROM a
WHERE a.order_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM other_table)
```